# Documentation similar to open API for IoT protocols like MQTT for open data sharing

Tags: mqtt, data-transfer

A lot of documentation exists for RESTful APIs via tools like [Swagger](https://swagger.io). But I am looking for a documentation tool or something in the likes for open data sharing for protocols like MQTT or OPC-UA.

A practical scenario maybe where I have a data source which I publish in a timely fashion to an MQTT Broker and I make avail the broker's address as well as the documentation of the topics which can be subscribed to, what is the data format etc. I actually haven't stumbled upon anything of the sort except for the respective RESTful APIs to the Databases where these data are stored and called in the end to query dumps of such data.

Are there already software tools, standardization bodies, etc. that are looking into such aspects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check AsyncAPI: https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/getting-started/coming-from-openapi/

From their website:

> Open source tools to easily build and maintain your event-driven architecture. All powered by the AsyncAPI specification, the industry standard for defining asynchronous APIs.